# Find a simpler description for each of the following rings.

Tags: field-theory

Find a simpler description for each of the following rings:

a) $\mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^5+x^3)$

b) $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x-2,x^2+3x)$

**Solution of (a):**
$$
\mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^5+x^3)
\cong \mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^3(x^2+1))
$$

Note that $x^3,x^2+1$ are pairwise relatively prime in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$. By Chinese Remainder Theorem,
$$
\mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^3(x^2+1)) 
\cong \mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^3) \times \mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^2+1)
\cong \mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^3) \times \mathbb{Q}[i]
$$

- Is this correct? **Yes**

**Solution of (b):**
$$
\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x-2,x^2+3x)
\cong \mathbb{Z}[x]/(x-2, x, x+3)
$$

Note that $x, x-2, x+3$ are pairwise relatively prime in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$. By Chinese Remainder Theorem,
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x, x-2, x+3)
& \cong \mathbb{Z}[x]/(x) \times \mathbb{Z}[x]/(x-2) \times \mathbb{Z}[x]/(x+3) \\
& \cong \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}[x]/(x-2) \times \mathbb{Z}[x]/(x+3)
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

- Is this correct? **Refer to solution below.**

Comment: I'm not sure that ${\bf Z}/(x-2,x+3)$ makes sense, since $x-2$ and $x+3$ aren't elements of $\bf Z$.

Comment: Also, you seem to be assuming that the ideal generated by $x^2+3x$ contains $x$ and $x+3$, which it doesn't.

Comment: Similarly, the ideal generated by $x^3(x^2+1)$ contains neither $x^3$ nor $x^2+1$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Okay. Then how should I be doing this problem?

Comment: One difficulty is that I'm not sure there's a universally accepted concept of "simpler description" in the context of ring theory. $${\bf Q}[x]/(x^5+x^3)\sim{\bf Q}[x]/(x^3)\oplus{\bf Q}[x]/(x^2+1)$$ and the first summand is polynomials of degree at most two with rational coefficients and multiplication modulo $x^3$, while the 2nd summand is (isomorphic to) ${\bf Q}(i)$. Is this simpler than what we started with? I don't know.

Comment: @GerryMyerson This is a qual question that I am studying for. So I can't say more about the phrase "simpler description." I know the problem is 40 pts (20 each part). So I feel like more might have to be done.

Comment: I'd recommend asking whoever it was that set (or marked) the exam, what kind of answer they were looking for. For the second problem, start by noting that $10$ is in the ideal generated by $x-2$ and $x^2+3x$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I edited my post based on your notes.

Comment: Why do I plug in x=2 into $x^2+3x$ instead of splitting it up like in part (a)?

Comment: First of all, in a) the ideal is generated by a product, in b) the ideal is generated by two items, so they are very different questions. Think about the difference between ${\bf Z}/(6)$ and ${\bf Z}/(2,3)$. Then note that when you divide $x^2+3x$ by $x-2$ the remainder is $10$; $x^2+3x=(x-2)(x+5)+10$.

Comment: Any thoughts on my solution to b)?

Comment: Are you still here?

Comment: Not polite, to ask a question and refuse to engage when you get an answer.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I have been in the hospital for 2 weeks. So I think I'm not being the impolite one. I'm still recovering so I will answer once I get a chance to recover. Thank you for your help

Comment: OK, my apologies. I wish you a speedy recovery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to answer b). From $x^2+3x=(x-2)(x+5)+10$, we see that $(x-2,x^2+3x)=(x-2,10)$. Now any $p(x)$ in ${\bf Z}[x]$ can be written as $(x-2)q(x)+c$ for some $q(x)$ in ${\bf Z}[x]$ and some integer $c$, and then $(x-2)q(x)+10r+s$ for some integers $r,s$ with $0\le s\le9$. So our ring is isomorphic to ${\bf Z}/10{\bf Z}$, the integers modulo ten.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution for (b):** Note that $x-2=0$ when $x=2$. Then $x^2+3x$ at $x=2$ is $10$. Hence the ideal $(x-2,x^2+3x)=(10)$. So
$$\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x-2,x^2+3x) \cong \mathbb{Z}[x]/(10) \cong \mathbb{Z}_{10}[x]$$

**This is correct?**

Comment: $x$ and $2$ are the same as elements of the ring, but not as elements of ${\bf Z}_{10}[x]$.

Comment: So how should I write up this proof?